# Is there any way or a formula to calculate the error of Euler's method and Runge-Kutta 4

Tags: numerical-methods, runge-kutta

When modeling a system with a step h1 using the simple Euler method, the error a1 was obtained, and the 4th order Runge-Kutta method obtained the error b1.
How can i determine the values ​​of errors a2 and b2 that will be obtained by modeling this system with a step of h2.

I tried formulas
a2 = a1(h1 / h2),
b2 = b1(h1 / h2)⁴
But I'm not sure if these formulas are correct.
I have

```
h1 = 10^-5
a1 = 3.0 * 10^-3
b1 = 0.2 * 10^-12
h2 = 5 * 10^-3
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calculating the error, but estimating from one error to the next. Or calculating an estimate for the error.

**Mainly**, your formulas need to be the other way around, `h2/h1`. You are using the model

```
error a = C_a * h + O(h^2)
      b = C_b * h^4 + O(h^5)
```

The flow of information is: from `a1`and `h1` determine guess for `C_a`, and with that compute the guess for `a2`. Thus

```
a2 ~= C_a*h2 ~= (a1/h1)*h2 = a1*(h2/h1)
b2 ~= C_b*h2^4 ~= (b1/h1^4)*h2^4 = b1 *(h2/h1)^4
```

---

The error as function of the step size usually has a V shape in a loglog plot, falling like `1/h` for small step sizes, then rising linearly as per the order, then becoming wavy then chaotic for step sizes near the stability boundary. See for example

- [first and middle section for the second order Heun methd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3609842/numerical-analysis-heuns-method)
- [all sections with RK4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3235194/truncation-error-with-growing-step-size)

So to get a correct estimate one needs that `h1` and `h2` are both in the second or middle segment where the error behaves as per the error order of the method.

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you please tell briefly?

Comment: Yes, h1 and h2 are correct 100%, i want to estimate a2 and b2

Comment: Thank you. For the first method (simple Euler) I got the value of error a2 equals 1.5, so the error is very high, what to do?

Comment: Can you please tell me what's wrong if the error is high?

Comment: Could you add your data to your question text? From a single number alone nothing much can be said. Depending on the scale of the solution, this could even be a small error.

Comment: I have:
    h1 = 10^-5,
    a1 = 3.0 * 10^-3,
    b1 = 0.2 * 10^-12,
    h2 = 5 * 10^-3

Comment: This does indeed suggest that the scale of the system is largish, about 100, giving constants C_a = 3*100^1 and C_b = 0.2*100^4. If you make the step size 500 times larger, the error will increase accordingly.

Comment: And so what? 1.5 is correct?

Comment: Yes. In Euler, if the step size is 500 times larger, the error also gets 500 times larger.